# Passing Data From View back to the HttpPost method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

Alright so i want to pass data from the view back to Post Method in the controller.

The View :

```
    @model IEnumerable< MvcMobile.Models.Trips>

<p>Time : @ViewBag.titi</p>
<p>ID :@ViewBag.iid </p>

<p>From : @ViewBag.From</p>
<p>To :@ViewBag.To </p>


Avaibliabe Trips : 
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if ( item.Time==ViewBag.titi)
    {
    <p>@item.TripID</p>
}
}
```

My HttpGet Method in the controller :

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Book2(MvcMobile.Models.TicketsBooked tik)
    {

        ViewBag.titi = tik.Time;
        ViewBag.iid = tik.TicketID;
        ViewBag.from = tik.From;
        ViewBag.To = tik.To;
        var TripsList = db.Trips.ToList();
        return View(TripsList);



    }
```

In This case i cant use a dynamic object to pass variable since the model is **IEnumerable**

i want to pass one or two textBoxes back to the controller, how can i do that ?

an **alternative question** would be how can i do the same functionality in the view without making the model **IEnumberable** ?

and thanks alot.

Comment: i dont know how to use ajax, this is why im asking this question, i want a way to pass the data, and about the object, i cant do "html.textboxfor(u=>u.something)", an errors shows up whenever i type it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on using view models. Basically it's best practice to only pass relevant data to the view. So instead on passing a model of IEnumerable you would have a view model with a property of IEnumerable plus the extra properties you want to post back to your controller.

So for example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MvcMobile.Models.Trips> Trips { get; set; }
    public string ExtraValue { get; set; }
}
```

and your view would be:

```
@foreach(var trip in Model.Trips)
{
     <p>Do stuff</p>
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExtraValue)
```

Your post method would then accept a ViewModel.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Book2(ViewModel viewModel) 
{
}
```

You can read up more on view models [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) or by searching Google / SO. There are many, many examples.

Comment: i just tried this and i got the following error : "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcMobile.Models.Trips]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcMobile.Models.ViewModel1'."  any idea ?

Comment: Because you are still passing db.Trips to your view. You will need to create a new ViewModel and set the Trips property to db.Trips. `var viewModel = new ViewModel { Trips = db.Trips.ToList() }; return View(viewModel);`